# Project Euler, #3 curiosity

Tags: c

Project Euler - 3 --- PROBLEM

I am a beginnner in the art of programming and I started to do the Project Euler problems.

I have tried to do the 3rd problem in C, but I don't understand why it's not working.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main ()
    {
            int prime = 0;
            long long number, factor, primeFactor = 0, i;
            printf("\n\nNumber :");
            scanf("%lld", &number);
            factor = number;
            while (primeFactor == 0) {
                    factor --;
                    if (number % factor == 0) {
                            for (i = 2; i < factor; i++) {
                                    if (factor % i == 0) {
                                            prime = 0;
                                    }
                            }
                            if (prime) {
                                    primeFactor = factor;
                            }
                    prime = 0;
                    }
            }
            if (primeFactor == 0) {
                    printf("\nIt has no prime factors.\n\n");
            }
            else printf("\n%lld\n", primeFactor);
            return 0;
    }
```

So, can someone explain to me why it does not work ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Please quote the problem statement in the question so people don't have to google for it. Then tell what your program outputs and what it should output instead.

Comment: I get a floating point exception error

Comment: 1) `prime` never set to nonzero.

Comment: Thanks ! I think that was the problem. Sorry for useless post.

Comment: 2)  you need to exit the loop when `factor` become 1.

Comment: Thanks ! I also noticed that factor -- should be put at the end of the loop, because the largest prime factor could be the number itself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. About the debugging, i will try to learn it later, because temporarely I "play" with the Linux commands to get familiar with the basics and I think it would be too complicated for now. Also, I'm sorry for my awful English, it's not my natal language.

Comment: @No_One: 1. Your English is fine. Don't worry about it. 2. Debugging is the most important skill you must develop as a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the logic on the inner loop wrong, just as BLUEPIXY hinted, you need to do the opposite:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
        int prime = 0;
        long long number, factor, primeFactor = 0, i;
        printf("\n\nNumber :");
        scanf("%lld", &number);
        factor = number;
        while (primeFactor == 0) {
                factor--;
                printf("%lld %lld\n",number,factor);
                if (number % factor == 0) {
                        for (i = 2; i < factor; i++) {
                                if (factor % i == 0) {
                                        prime = 1;
                                }
                        }
                        if (!prime) {
                                primeFactor = factor;
                        }
                prime = 0;
                }
        }
        if (primeFactor == 0) {
                printf("\nIt has no prime factors.\n\n");
        }
        else printf("\n%lld\n", primeFactor);
        return 0;
}
```

Also: `1` is not prime, you need to check for that, too. Neither does the input itself gets checked (must be greater than 1 here).

Please learn how to use a debugger. No, really, knowing how to use the debugger for the language you learn is as important as to learn the language itself.